# Programmatically sending 1,000 transactions at once in JavaScript - how many transactions can 1 wallet send at once?

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

I'm writing a script that will send 10 MATIC to 1,000 addresses. What I have written so far seems to achieve this on my local Ganache server (pretending ETH is MATIC). But I am assuming this is going to fall over and die on the polygon mainnet? What would be considered better practice?

> I have considered just using `wait()` on the tx response, so it will just do 1 at a time, but this is a last resort as it'll be slow.

```js
import {providers, utils, Wallet} from 'ethers'
import {NonceManager} from '@ethersproject/experimental'

const SECRET_KEY = 'xyz...'
const RPC = 'http://127.0.0.1:7545' // ganache server
const GAS_LIMIT = 100_000

async function execute() {
  
  const wallets = [
    '0x00...' // x 1,000
  ]
  
  // Load and validate secret key
  const provider = new providers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC)
  const signer = new Wallet(SECRET_KEY, provider)
  const publicKey = await signer.getAddress()

  // Handles the nonce for each transaction
  const manager = new NonceManager(signer)
  
  for (const wallet of wallets) {

    const tx = {
      from: publicKey,
      to: wallet,
      value: utils.parseEther('10'),
      gasLimit: utils.hexlify(GAS_LIMIT),
      gasPrice: await signer.getGasPrice(),
    }

    await manager.sendTransaction(tx)
      .then(async response => {
        console.log('success', response.hash)
        // I could use `await response.wait()` here for synchronicity, but its super slow
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
}

execute()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('all done')
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error', error)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use Web3 Batch Request

Listing an Example Below

var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);

var batch = new web3.BatchRequest();
batch.add(web3.eth.getBalance.request('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'latest', callback));
batch.add(contract.methods.balance(address).call.request({from: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'}, callback2));
batch.execute();

This Will Excecute the Transactions in a batch.

But if you are using A public JSON-RPC then there might be  an limit of Batch Request.

Comment: is web3 browser only? Do you have a link to the package/docs? ty!

Comment: No Web3 is not browser only.

You can refer here for the Docs 
[web3js docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.1/web3-eth.html#batchrequest)